# PHP extensions for vscode can't handle code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, oxid

I would love to switch from Sublime to VSCode completely. While developing Go is a great experience, PHP is not much fun with some libraries.
At work, we use the OXID e-Commerce solution for many projects. The biggets has more than 150MB in PHP code.

The two big PHP extensions (the ones by Felix Becker and Hvy Industries) both fail to work properly with OXID. I tried to let both index for a whole weekend, but I get no results except 100% CPU load. I think I know why, I can try to elaborate if someone is interested.

All I really miss/need is a simple "Go to definition". In Sublime, I have this simple "right click -> go to definition" which lists all func/method definitions with this name. It's not perfect, but better than nothing. Is there something similar to this for VSCode? Or anybody who had more luck with OXID projects and VSCode?

Comment: have you tried the "go to definition" for vscode here? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_go-to-definition

Comment: Thanks samAlvin. I believe this does only work with a language extension that can actually index the project, but I'll take a second look.

Comment: do you use OXID community edition or any of the encrypted editions? I tried vscode with CE some months ago and I didn't have any problems. Or maybe encrypted modules?

Comment: I guess encrypted modules are part of the problem, yes. We use all OXID editions for different projects btw. Sublime can still show me the symbols it can read though (which is absolutely fine for me).

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @Blkc no, oxcept PHPStorm with a plugin, no IDE can handle OXID code, because of their weird class extension system

Comment: @tsdtsdtsd I am currently using https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense because of my environment being in php5.6. Seems to allow me to go to definition and peak. May be give that a try?

Comment: @Blkc I'll give it a try. Basically, if it tries to understand/parse/interpret PHP code, it will not work. If it just searches for symbols, it will work. By now I believe that the weird inheritance system for custom modules in OXID is the problem. You have to extend from classes that don't exist and write the real class you want to extend into some config files. I guess they swing the reflection hammer and mix it up with some goat blood and chicken heads to make it work somehow...